# List Users currently chatting with - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have to create a page where i have to list all the users who are sending message to me or the users whom i am sending message. So, i can be receiver and sender also of the message. Also, message should be the latest one. Just like the list page we have in whats app. Like:

```
User1
some latest message       <
----------------------------
User2
some other latest message >
----------------------------
User3
some latest message       <
----------------------------
User4
some latest message       <
----------------------------
User5
some latest message       >
----------------------------
```

I have a user table with normal details of every user and a message table with the message. I want to know can i do the above list with just a query? I tried this query:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_messages WHERE sender_id=1 OR receiver_id=1 GROUP BY sender_id, receiver_id ORDER BY message_timestamp DESC";
```

but this SQL return the record group like:

[image]

here you can see i have two groups for user ids 1 and 2 but ideally i should only have one record for user ids combination 1 and 2. And more over they are not the latest messages. They return the oldest one. So, its just a list of users with messages are ever exchanged, sent or received.

Can any one please let me know what i am missing in the SQL to make it work? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say what the question is about, but I tend to think that you want to use `AND` instead of `OR` - `WHERE sender_id=1 AND receiver_id=1`

Comment: Apologies if i am not clear, No i cannot use AND, it will not return any value if i will use AND. I cannot send message to me. I just have to create a list of users with whom i am chatting. It is irrespective that i am sending message or i am receiving message. Hope i am clear now.

Comment: That seems like it would set it to only retrieve messages one person sent to themselves.

Comment: I just have to create a list of users with whom i am chatting. It is irrespective that i am sending message or i am receiving message. Hope i am clear now

Comment: can you add a "having max(creation_time) " on the message table? assuming you have a field like that. that should filter out older messages and return only the latest message you care about.

Comment: *"where i have to list all the users who are sending message to me"* - Define "me". Do **you** have a specific `id` in there? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probally you should use a union in a nested subquery, it's not an out_of_the_box query:

```
SELECT
    m.message,
    m.message_timestamp,
    IF(s.user_id = 1, r.user_name, s.user_name) talk_to,
    IF(s.user_id = 1, 'out', 'in') in_out
FROM
    (SELECT
        me,
        other,
        MAX(message_id) max_id
    FROM
        (SELECT
            sender_id me,
            receiver_id other,
            message_id
        FROM
           messages
        WHERE sender_id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            receiver_id me,
            sender_id other,
            message_id
        FROM
            messages
        WHERE receiver_id = 1
    ) mu
    GROUP BY me,other
    ) lm
JOIN
    messages m
    ON lm.max_id = m.message_id
JOIN
    users s
    ON m.sender_id = s.user_id
JOIN
    users r
    ON m.sender_id = r.user_id
```